# Add textbox in place of Angular-DataTable default search box using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-datatables

How to add custom textbox in place of datatable default search text box. Need to call API for every keyup, so need to hide original textbox and add custom textbox, Tried below code for replacing textbox with custom textbox. Tried below code with `Renderer2`, please help me on this..

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const input = this.renderer.createElement('input');
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, input);
    const textboxes = document.getElementById('textboxes');
    this.renderer.appendChild(textboxes, div);
            
   }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/replace-search-box)

Comment: Rajasekhar there are a "crazy" reason to use a library that use jQuery (in my opinion create an Angular library that depends on jQuery is not a good idea) or you use Angular 6?

Comment: Well, apologies by my before comment. Your code don't work because you can not add an input with "angular event" (the `<input (keyup)="globalSearch()"..>`). You sould use Renderer2 to create an input element and to add events: see the docs:https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2